# Is it possible to replicate MATLAB circshift approach in Armadillo?

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, armadillo, conways-game-of-life

I found this piece of code for MATLAB that lets you count neighbors for Conway's Game of Life using circshift and what I think has something to do with convolution (not too proud of my knowledge, still learning and would love your explanation of what is happening)

```
for t=1:T
neighbors = circshift(X, [1, 0]) + circshift(X, [-1, 0]) +  circshift(X, [0, 1]) +  circshift(X, [0, -1]) + ...
circshift(X, [1, 1]) + circshift(X, [-1, 1]) + circshift(X, [1, -1]) + circshift(X, [-1, -1]);

X(find(((neighbors > 3) | (neighbors < 2))  & X)) = 0;
X(find((neighbors == 3) & ~X)) = 1;
```

What I am trying to do is the same, but in C++ Armadillo.
Is it possible to do this? Asking, since I haven't found a circshift function, just shift() or conv2()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shift()` function works like in Matlab for `vec` types but for `mat` you must do it twice (in each dimension) like

```
arma::mat circshift(arma::mat A, int r, int c)
{
    return arma::shift(arma::shift(A,r,0),c,1);
}
```